# Using value returned of script executed on remote host

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

So I am executing this code on the local host which is accessing a remote host and executing another script:

```
count=$(ssh -i /home/ubuntu/***** "sh /home/ubuntu/michael/LogScript/backUpLog.sh "$1" "$2" "$3"")
echo "$count"
exit "$count"
```

And this is the code it is remotely connecting to and running:

```
count=$(grep "^$(date -d -"$1"minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" /var/log/*****/*****.log | wc -l)
if [ "$count" -ge "$2" -a "$count" -lt "$3" ]
then
    exit 1
fi  
if [ "$count" -ge "$3" ]
then 
    exit 2
fi
exit 0
```

The ssh is working correctly as I have testing with very simple scripts, but when I run the above I get `exit: 3: Illegal number:` It doesn't say anything more than this. Is it because of the way I am calling count in the local script?

Comment: If you add `| xxd` to the end of the `echo` line what do you get? I'm going to also guess that your script file has dos line endings. Does running `dos2unix` on your script file help?

Comment: exit "$count" .. in the script. Seems like that value is not a number while exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Your remote script returns an exit code but no output. Your local script ignores the exit code and tries to capture output.

You can change your local script to use the exit code instead:

```
ssh -i /home/ubuntu/***** "sh /home/ubuntu/michael/LogScript/backUpLog.sh $1 $2 $3"
exitCode=$?

echo "Command exited with $exitCode"
exit "$exitCode"
```